# how to return a value in a column that is not missing values in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm still trying to delete (drop) every column that contains missing values ​​but the output results are only the index column that appears

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.util.testing.makeMissingDataframe().reset_index()
df.head()
df = df.dropna(axis='columns',how='all')
df.head()
```

Comment: Well, if you have at least one missing value per column, it is normal that it drops all columns, no?

Answer (score 0):

The code that is mentioned in your question doesn't drop any column, since dropna contains the parameter 'all'. it means that the column will be dropped only when all of the values in the column are 'NaN', which doesn't happens in your code.

If you drop it without this parameter -

```
df = df.dropna(axis='columns')
```

The **index** column is the only one that will be kept since it doesn't contain any 'NaN' values.

I suggest you to look into the documentation of dropna [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)